# How to check if all strings in a string array are all digits?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string, and I want it to be only digits. I tried this, using `LINQ`:

```
string[] values = { "123", "a123" };
bool allStringsContaintsOnlyDigits = true;

foreach(string value in values)
{
    if(!value.All(char.IsDigit))
    {
        allStringsContaintsOnlyDigits = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(allStringsContaintsOnlyDigits) { /* Do Stuff */ }
```

But a loop for only two strings (and it is guaranteed that I have two strings) is a bit tedious...

So I thought maybe doing this:

```
if(values[0].All(char.isDigit) && values[1].All(char.isDigit)) { /* Do Stuff */ }
```

But is there a more elegant way? Something like:

```
values.All(char.IsDigit) // for all strings
```

Thanks.

**Note:** negative numbers need to be rejected. Meaning: `-125` should return `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(values[0] + values[1]).All(char.IsDigit);
```

since they're both just strings, this concatenates them and then uses LINQ over each character.

Comment: All answers here are very good but this is the most readable and simple for me. Thanks!

Comment: `String.Concat(values)` is more *general* implementation than `(values[0] + values[1])`

Comment: It is. But it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 14):

How about

```
values.All(s => s.All(Char.IsDigit));
```

That checks that for *all strings* in the sequence *all characters* are digits.

Comment: I struggled between this answer and @ManuelSchweigert's answer. Both are great but I find his more readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
values.SelectMany(s => s).All(char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: `SelectMany(s => s)` is the same than `All()` isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Why not try it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this.

**Using Regular Expression.**

```
bool allints = values.All(x=> Regex.IsMatch(x, @"^[0-9]*$"));
```

Another approach using `int.Parse`, but please mind max (int) value allowed is 2147483647.

```
int value;
bool allints = values.All(x=>x[0] != '-' && int.TryParse(x.Trim(), out vlaue));
```

Comment: `TryParse` will fail on *negative numbers* (you should *reject* `-123`), *very long numbers* (you should *accept* `123456789123456789`)

Comment: Yeah true there is an integer limitation, but I doubt whether we could reject negative numbers.

Comment: question says "all digits" and accepted `"-123"` is not all digits, since minus sign is not a digit.

Comment: I did not write it in the answer but actually, the REASON I need this feature is to reject minuses. I would add this info to the question.

Comment: @Sipo Updated my answer to reject negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko

Comment: @Hari Prasad: another shortcoming of `TryParse` is that the method is *smart* one: `"   123   "` (please, notice heading and trailing *spaces*) will be parsed and *accepted* when it should be rejected.

Comment: @Hari Prasad: your current implementation throws exception on *empty strings* at `x[0]`

Answer (score 2):

To check if *string* is all digits:

```
  String value = ...

  boolean allDigits = value.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

To check if `IEnumerable<string>` (`string[]` included) is all digits:

```
  String[] source = ...

  boolean allDigits = source
    .All(value => value
      .All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```

Please, notice, that I've *changed* initial `Char.IsDigit(c)` in the question to `c >= '0' && c <= '9')` since `Char.IsDigit` returns *true* not only on `0..9`, but on many *other characters*, e.g. Persian digits: `۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷`...

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub: if strings like `"۱۲۳ ۴ ۵"` or `"12۰۰45"` should be *accepted*, then `Char.IsDigit` is the *right choice*; however if *all digits* means in fact all `0..9` then `c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'` is the implmenttation